# How to sort a queue with a temporary queue?

Tags: java, sorting, queue, stack, temporary

I'm very amateur and bad with coding.
there's a queue with elements and another empty queue. and these queues aren't arrays but generic with this empty queue you have to sort the original queue. The way: dequeue the q1head to other q2 ---> if q1 head < q2lastelement then enqueue q1head else enqueue q1head to q2.
I understand how it goes but I can't code. could someone code this for me please, because this is a a homework for school. :)

Comment: You need to make an attempt first and post the code you've tried so that people can help with errors. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hint - a 2 queue sort can use the logic from a [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) for arrays.